# Does Core Data autoupdate a many to many relationship on saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have 2 database tables in Sqlite and using Core Data / NSManagedObjects:

```
Users
user_id
name
belongsToGroups (many groups)

Groups
group_id
title
groupMembers (many users)
```

By using core data to save a Group and add users (and add him to a group) like so:

```
Groups *coreData = nil;

coreData = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Groups" inManagedObjectContext:context];
request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Users"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user_id = %@", user_id];

results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


coreData.group_id = group_id
coreData.title = title
[coreData addGroupMembersObject:[results lastObject]];
```

Is it correct to say that core data manages the Users to many groups and groups with many users with the above code?

Comment: Yes it does. By looking at your relationship, it is clear there is an inverse relationship between the entities. So Core Data manages them for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if the relationships are set-up as *inverse relationships* of each other.
Modifying one relationship automatically updates the inverse relationship.

*Remark:* I would call the entities "User" and "Group", because each object of the
entity represents a *single* user or group. I would also (but that might be a matter
of taste) call the relationships just "groups" and "users".

Comment: @chris: I have no experience with Parse, so I cannot help with PFRelations. I would suggest that you post that as a separate question.